# ASP VB - Dropdownlist data to label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to ASP.net programming and I have a question about how to pass data that's retrieved from a dropdownlist and to then populate it into a label so it can be stored in a db. This should be an easy answer from someone but i'm stuck. I'm in pretty deep right now and this is all that's left to complete my form. Here's the code below;

```
    Private Sub FillPersonList()

    Dim strConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQL2K-ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct(LName +',  '+ FName) AS 'Name', PNumber FROM [SQL88K].ASD.dbo.Check WHERE insertdatetime BETWEEN getdate() - 7 AND getdate() And Room = @Room"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Room", DDRoom.SelectedItem.Value)

    Dim objDs As New DataSet()
    Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    con.Open()
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs)
    con.Close()
    If objDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        DDPerson.DataSource = objDs.Tables(0)
        DDPerson.DataTextField = "PName"
        DDPerson.DataValueField = "PName"
        lblPNumber.Text = "PNumber"          'This is where i'm trying to populate the label!
        DDPerson.DataBind()
        DDPerson.Items.Insert(0, "<--Select Person-->")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Putting something in a label has nothing to do with storing it in a db.  Did your question get slightly garbled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you're trying to do is get the value the user picks and do something with it, whether storing it in a db or putting it in a label.  For that, you need to wait for the user to post back.  (Or use Javascript, but since you mentioned a db I assume you want to do this on the server side.)

There are a couple of ways to structure things.  One of the simplest would be to create an event handler for the `DDPerson` control's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, and set the value of the label there:

```
  lblPNumber.Text = DDPerson.SelectedValue

  ' Run code to update your database with the value of DDPerson.SelectedValue.
```

But, you're not binding the `PNumber` to the drop down list.  So you'd have to change your binding code to this:

```
    DDPerson.DataTextField = "PName"
    DDPerson.DataValueField = "PNumber"
    DDPerson.DataBind()
    DDPerson.Items.Insert(0, "<--Select Person-->")
```

Comment: I have a cascade of dropdowns and the last dropdown I need it to select a person's name from it and then it will populate a label for the person's number (employee number). Is it possible to do it this way? thank you

Comment: It is very possible.  You need to decide whether the necessary post-back will happen when the value is selected from the final drop down (in which case you'll need to set the `AutoPostBack` property of that dropdown to True) or whether the user has to do some other action to make it post back.